# Binding the roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor role to Google Cloud MIG instances with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, identity-aware-proxy, gce-instance-group

I have created a Google Cloud Compute Engine managed instance group (MIG) in Terraform using the `google_compute_instance_template` and `google_compute_instance_group_manager` resources and would like to set up access via the identity aware proxy (IAP).

When creating a standalone Compute Engine instance, you can use one of the three `google_iap_tunnel_instance_iam_*` resources to attach the `roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor` role to the instances, for example:

```
resource "google_iap_tunnel_instance_iam_member" "member" {
  project = "my-project"

  zone     = "europe-west2-a"
  instance = "my-instance"
  role     = "roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor"
  member   = "user:foo@bar.com"
}
```

However, with a MIG, we don't have Terraform references to the actual instances (and even if we did, they're dynamic anyway), so it seems we can't use the `google_iap_tunnel_instance_iam_*` resources.

I can't find a Terraform-native way of doing this, without granting `roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor` to the members at the *project* level. However, this is not always desirable, and sometimes *instance* level bindings are required.

Is this currently possible with MIGs?

Answer (score 1):

In situations like these, you can often use [IAM conditions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview): The idea is to grant a role on the project level, but to constrain it to a subset of resources. Unfortunately, IAM conditions are currently not supported for IAP-TCP, so that approach won't work here.

Assuming you use OS Login, the following might be a viable workaround though:

1. Grant `roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor` on the project (applying to all instances)
2. Grant `roles/compute.osLogin` on the project, with a condition that constrains the role to instances that match your MIG's naming scheme:

   ```
   resource.type == 'compute.googleapis.com/Instance' && 
   resource.name.extract('/instances/{name}').startsWith('mymig-')
   ```